# Как добавить в поле(коллекцию) класса?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

подскажите пожалуйста. Есть класс
Client

```
public partial class Client
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Client()
    {
        condition = new HashSet<condition>();
        PhoneNumber = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string DriverLicense { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string Passport { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<condition> condition { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Класс PhoneNumber

```
    public partial class PhoneNumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Id_client { get; set; }

    public string Ph_number { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Action AddClietn в Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddClient(ViewModel clients)
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel()
        {
            cl = new Client
            {
                Name = clients.cl.Name,
                Passport = clients.cl.Passport,
                DriverLicense = clients.cl.DriverLicense,
                PhoneNumber = clients.pH. ?????????
            }
        };
        db.Client.Add(vm.cl);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

viewModel

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public Client cl { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber pH { get; set; }
}
```

и View

@model showroom_eliteauto_new_.Models.ViewModel

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Данные о клиенте</legend>
    <form action="/Main/AddClient" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Введите ФИО</p></td>
                <td><input name="cl.Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Серия/Номер паспорта</p></td>
                <td><input name="cl.Passport"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Номер водительского удостоверения</p></td>
                <td><input name="cl.DriverLicense"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Номер телефона</p></td>
                <td><input name="pH.Ph_number" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Как передать значение из View в Controller и принять в PhoneNumber?
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Не используя js есть возможность?

Comment: Нет желающих подсказать?